# Show that the variance, $\mathbb E((x-\mathbb E(x))^2)$, can be written as $\mathbb E(x^2)-(\mathbb E(x))^2$

Tags: statistics, expectation

This question has been set in the Christmas work for the chemists at oxford uni and the hint that was given in the problem sheet was "does $\mathbb E(x)$ depend on $x$?".

There is a derivation on Wikipedia:
$$\mathbb E((x-\mathbb E(x))^2)$$
Expand the brackets (I get this bit)
$$\mathbb E(x^2-2x\mathbb E(x)+\mathbb E(x)^2)$$
Use the fact the expectation value of the sum of the terms is the same as the sum of the expectation values of the terms:
$$\mathbb E(x^2)-2\mathbb E(x\mathbb E(x))+\mathbb E(\mathbb E(x)^2)$$
This step isn't written explicitly in the derivation on Wikipedia but it must be the case. Now the step that I don't understand: $$\mathbb E(x^2)-2\mathbb E(x)\mathbb E(x)+\mathbb E(\mathbb E(x)^2)$$ Why does the term in the middle not change to $2\mathbb E(x)\mathbb E(\mathbb E(x))$?

Then collect the terms:$$\mathbb E(x^2)-\mathbb E(x)^2$$

**Also, this doesn't seem to utilise the hint given by my lecturer. Is there a better way of doing it?**

Comment: The expectation of a constant is the constant itself.

Comment: Next time, you may want to use \langle and \rangle to get $\langle x \rangle$

Comment: I Converted this to the somewhat common notation $\mathbb E(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expected value of a constant is a constant:

$$\begin{align}
E(a) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}af(x)dx
\\   &= a\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx
\\   &= a
\end{align}$$
since $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx = 1$ the total probability.
Hence,
$$\begin{align}
E\left((x-E(x))^2\right) &= E\left(x^2 -2xE(x) + E(x)^2\right)
\\ &= E(x^2) -2E(x)E(x) +E(x)^2 
\\ &= E(x^2) - E(x)^2
\end{align}$$

Comment: It did not translate nicely. I'm just learning the syntax.

Comment: I edited your post to improve formatting.  You can press the "edit" button to see how it is typed out.  Thank you for your contribution to math.se , but please be careful that your answer is not a duplicate of a given answer.

Comment: @  DanielV Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

The hint is to be understood as
$\mathbb E(x)$ only depends on the distribution of $x$, but not on the samples, thus an equivalent formula to that statement would be
$$\mathbb E(\mathbb E(x)) = \mathbb E(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

Lets set $E[X]=\mu=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)dx$

$$\text{Var}(X) = E[(X-\mu)^2] = E[X^2-2\mu X+\mu^2]$$

Now calculate this expectation:

$$\begin{align}
E[X^2-2\mu X+\mu^2] &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (x^2-2\mu x+\mu^2)f(x)dx
\\ &=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2f(x)dx - 2\mu\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)dx + \mu^2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx
\\ &= E[X^2]-2\mu\mu+\mu^2
\\ &= E[X^2]-\mu^2
\end{align}$$

For more details on the subject consult Sheldon Ross *Introduction to Probability Models*.

Comment: I added the alignment that I believe you were working on.  If you choose "edit" then you can see how it is typed out.  Hope that helps~~