# Basic function manipulation and simplification question for $f((x-f(x))^2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics

I've run into a bit of a wall trying to understand why the following two equations are equivalent:

$$f((x-f(x))^2) = f(x^2)-f(x)^2$$

I'm running into this with calculating population variance in statistics, which is an area I understand, but I'm just not seeing the math here. I know at least for this application these two equations are equivalent, but am not familiar enough with function manipulation to see the logic behind it. The farthest I get is to go ahead and square the first function to get the following:

$$f(x^2-2xf(x)+f(x)^2)$$

...how do you continue to manipulate the terms and result in $f(x^2)-f(x)^2$?

Comment: That won't hold for most arbitrary functions. Can you give us more information about $f$, what it's supposed to represent, or a formula if there is one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a guess, but perhaps $f$ is the expectation operator and $x$ is a random variable? If you're trying to understand why
$$E[(X-E(X))^2] = E(X^2)-E(X)^2\;,$$
then [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1059274/215011) might help. Another derivation can be found [here](http://www.wyzant.com/resources/lessons/math/statistics_and_probability/expected_value/variance).

Comment: Ok, so I'm making a mistake in assuming that the expectation operator E(x) is similar to any function f(x)? I was thinking they both act on an "x" domain and are therefore functions of x, in this case E(x) being the integral of x*f(x) where f(x) is a probability density function. Since this ultimately puts the concepts in the form of f(x), g(x), etc., I was thinking this generalized them to be true for all functions...unless stats is special.

Comment: Since random variables are functions, the expectation operator is a function that acts on functions! You should think of it as an operation similar to integration. It's the linearity properties of integration that we are using to justify the derivation (and the same rules of integration have to be followed in stats, so stats isn't special :)