# Product of two independent, random draws is usually less than the square of a random draw. Why?

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Suppose a uniform distribution, `D` over positive real numbers. On average, the product of two independent draws from `D` is less than the square of a random draw from `D`. I wrote a MWE in R code that simulates the above. My question is, why?

```
n_sim = 1000000
min_val = 1
max_val = 10000000000
a = runif(n   = n_sim,
          min = min_val, max = max_val)
b = runif(n   = n_sim,
          min = min_val, max = max_val)
c = runif(n   = n_sim,
          min = min_val, max = max_val)
table(a<b)
table(a*b < c^2)
```

Comment: Because $E[X^2]-E[X]^2 = E[(X-E[X])^2]>0$?

Comment: @Chappers is there a proof of that somewhere?

Comment: A proof of which bit?

Comment: The equation that @Chappers gave is just the formula for the variance, which is always greater than zero unless the random variable is a constant, in which case the variance is zero.

Comment: Doh. Yes, my question was dumb. Thanks all.

Comment: Did you mean to ask about the expected values or about the frequency of the one product being larger than the other?

Comment: @Bananach Yes. But I think Chappers and Jon Bown answer that, since E[X^2] is the expectation of the product of two independent draws from D and E[X]^2 is the square of one random draw from D, and by looking at the equation, which is just variance, their difference must be greater than zero since X is a random variable rather than a constant.

Comment: I didn't ask a yes/no question. Asking for expectations and asking for frequencies are different things. Your question seems like you are asking for the latter (you are computing where an equality holds, you are not computing expectations)

Comment: @Bananach Both.

Answer (score -1):

Your finding is true for any distribution, positive or not, uniform or not. Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent, each with the same distribution as $Z$. Your observation is that
$$E(XY -Z^2)\le0.\tag1$$
Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, the LHS of (1) equals $E(X)E(Y)=[E(Z)]^2$ so asserting (1) is the same as asserting
$$
[E(Z)]^2-E(Z^2)\le0.\tag2
$$
You can rearrange (2) to the form
$$
E(Z^2)-[E(Z)]^2\ge0,\tag3$$
which is a true statement for any $Z$ because the [LHS of (3) equals](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1059274/215011) $E[(Z-E(Z))^2]$, which is the expectation of a non-negative random variable (it's also the variance of $Z$).